# How to get Data into the model via elasticsearch get

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

```
public class News
{
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp{ get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public bool forstudents { get; set; }

    public List<link> links { get; set; }
    public List<imgs> imgs { get; set; }
}

public class link
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class imgs
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Model Description then i connect to the Server

```
var _esServer = new ElasticSearchServer("http://localhost:9200");
var _esIndex = _esServer.GetIndex("campusoffice");
var news = _esIndex.Get<News>("/news", int.MaxValue);
```

and it should get everything right but

he doesnt map the name and the value in the list elements

```
{
  "author": "soulseak",
  "title": "Awsome",
  "timestamp": 20130201,
  "content": "Erster",
  "forstudents": true,
  "links": {
    "myhome": "http://test.de"
  },
  "imgs": {
    "myhome": "http://test.de"
  }
}
```

the question is how to tell him what to put in name and value that myhome is in name and the url in value

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public class User {
    public User(string json) {
        var jsonObject = Json.Decode(json);
        MyName = (string)jsonObject.user.name;
        MyTeamName = (string)jsonObject.user.teamname;
        MyEmail = (string)jsonObject.user.email;
        Players = (DynamicJsonArray) jsonObject.user.players;
    }

    public string MyName{ get; set; }
    public string MyTeamName  { get; set; }
    public string MyEmail{ get; set; }
    public Array Players { get; set; }
}
```

But would need to assign the values manually.

Example using your model (0 index based only, you would need to write a loop) but using a direct RestFul call:

```
var url = "http://localhost:9200/campusoffice/news";
var client = new WebClient();
var json = client.DownloadString(url);
var jsonObject = Json.Decode(json);

var links = (DynamicJsonArray) jsonObject.links;
var imgs = (DynamicJsonArray) jsonObject.imgs;
var news = new News 
   { author = (string)jsonObject.author,
     links = new List<link>() };

var aLink = new link { name = (string)links[0].myhome, value = 
         (string)imgs[0].myhome };

news.links.Add(aLink);
```

I typed this roughly without compiling/testing but should give you an idea.

Comment: id like to asign it manualy but i dont even know how that works cause i dont know how to extract all values out of the index and asign them one by one

Comment: Do you get the Json data back successfully from ElasticSearch? Your question is to assign the Json data to your model. I'll update my answer using your model.

Comment: at the current point i get back everthing fine but links and imgs contain 1 element with the name = null and value = null

Comment: when one of the data types would be wrong it would make the element news= null but that doesnt seam to be the case it creates the object in the lists but doesnt fill its values

Comment: Because the property names of your model do not match the Json structure names.

Comment: then is the question what are the json structure names
myhome etc are variables not static member names

Comment: the problem is in your solution i dont know how many indexes there are and if theyr index id is 1-5 or 1 3 5 7

Comment: then the Json structure is not adhering to standards

Comment: http://localhost:9200/campusoffice/news/1
is the index 1 i cant get alle indexes in news or campusoffice alone

Comment: You can search across multiple indexes using the _all placeholder:
http://localhost:9200/_all. Please note that my answer was to provide a way to map a Json structure manually and not to dive into the ES API :)